# Is there a way to disable DST in pytz

Tags: python, pytz

I understand that pytz takes care of DST while performing time conversions.
However I would like to know is there an option in pytz to disable DST entirely during the computations?

Comment: For what reason? Timezones without DST are rather inaccurate.

Comment: Timezones without DST will provide time accurately without DST. Without DST or before applying DST is the solution I am looking for.

Comment: do you know that DST is not the only reason why the utc offset (or tzname) may change in a given timezone? Could you provide the context (what is the intent of your code) what is the input, what is the output?

Comment: OK...if offset changes tz db has to be updated. On the use-case front such a behaviour of disabling DST in computations might be useful in cases like , When certain countries suddenly changes their DST schedule which happened for few countries in the past 6 months

Comment: Input - Time in one Time Zone. Output - Time in another Time Zone without  DST